# Apple Style Scrollbar WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, scrollbar

I'm trying to reduce the size of the scrollbar control and make it more "Apple" like since it would fit my interface really well.

What I'm trying to achieve is something that looks like this:

[image]

So far all I have is this

```
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
            <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#8C8C8C" />
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="8"/>
            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="8" />
        </Style>
```

Working XAML

Implementation can be found at [Apple Style Scrollbar in WPF](http://sa.ndeep.me/post/apple-style-scrollbar-in-wpf)

```
    <!--Scrollbar Thumbs-->
<Style x:Key="ScrollThumbs" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                <Grid x:Name="Grid">
                    <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Fill="Transparent" />
                    <Border x:Name="Rectangle1" CornerRadius="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Height="Auto"  Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Tag" Value="Horizontal">
                        <Setter TargetName="Rectangle1" Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Rectangle1" Property="Height" Value="7" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<!--ScrollBars-->
<Style x:Key="{x:Type ScrollBar}" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
    <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="false" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#8C8C8C" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="8" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
                <Grid x:Name="GridRoot" Width="8" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="0.00001*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Track x:Name="PART_Track" Grid.Row="0" IsDirectionReversed="true" Focusable="false">
                        <Track.Thumb>
                            <Thumb x:Name="Thumb" Background="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Style="{DynamicResource ScrollThumbs}" />
                        </Track.Thumb>
                        <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                            <RepeatButton x:Name="PageUp" Command="ScrollBar.PageDownCommand" Opacity="0" Focusable="false" />
                        </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                        <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                            <RepeatButton x:Name="PageDown" Command="ScrollBar.PageUpCommand" Opacity="0" Focusable="false" />
                        </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                    </Track>
                </Grid>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger SourceName="Thumb" Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Value="{DynamicResource ButtonSelectBrush}" TargetName="Thumb" Property="Background" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger SourceName="Thumb" Property="IsDragging" Value="true">
                        <Setter Value="{DynamicResource DarkBrush}" TargetName="Thumb" Property="Background" />
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="Thumb" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal">
                        <Setter TargetName="GridRoot" Property="LayoutTransform">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="-90" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_Track" Property="LayoutTransform">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="-90" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="8" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Thumb" Property="Tag" Value="Horizontal" />
                        <Setter TargetName="PageDown" Property="Command" Value="ScrollBar.PageLeftCommand" />
                        <Setter TargetName="PageUp" Property="Command" Value="ScrollBar.PageRightCommand" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Is it OK to use this code? (E.g. in a non-free setting)

Comment: It's all open code, go ahead

Comment: thanks for share if i can use it and a bit modify it..

Comment: Thanks for final working XAML.

Comment: I know it's quite old post... I want to use the same code with some enhance style, but what I found that the repeat buttons are missing in this style. When I use the exact code in ResourceDictionery in  WPF those two buttons does not show up. Any idea how can I enable those two buttons.

Comment: Sandeep, you should add the working code as an answer, and not as part of your question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question.

Comment: @MikeNakis almost 9 years later?

Comment: I suppose 9 years ago stackoverflow had lower standards. If this had been posted in recent years it would have been closed within 10 minutes.  But, better late than never.

Comment: Bear in mind that you can reword the question as an actual question and then proceed to add an answer to it, and accept it.  Then, there will be no reason to close it.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

It's not very pretty and in all honesty I can't remember where it came from, there is something similar to what you're after in one of my project here, there is probably a lot in the style that's not required or is incorrect but may as well give it a shot.

```
 <!--Scrollbar Thumbs-->
        <Style x:Key="ScrollThumbs" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                        <Grid x:Name="Grid">
                            <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Fill="Transparent" />
                            <Border x:Name="Rectangle1" CornerRadius="10" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Height="Auto"  Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="Tag" Value="Horizontal">
                                <Setter TargetName="Rectangle1" Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
                                <Setter TargetName="Rectangle1" Property="Height" Value="7" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <!--ScrollBars-->
        <Style x:Key="{x:Type ScrollBar}" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
            <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="false" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightGray" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkGray" />
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="10" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
                        <Grid x:Name="GridRoot" Width="19" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="0.00001*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <Track x:Name="PART_Track" Grid.Row="0" IsDirectionReversed="true" Focusable="false">
                                <Track.Thumb>
                                    <Thumb x:Name="Thumb" Background="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Style="{DynamicResource ScrollThumbs}" />
                                </Track.Thumb>
                                <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                    <RepeatButton x:Name="PageUp" Command="ScrollBar.PageDownCommand" Opacity="0" Focusable="false" />
                                </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                    <RepeatButton x:Name="PageDown" Command="ScrollBar.PageUpCommand" Opacity="0" Focusable="false" />
                                </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                            </Track>
                        </Grid>

                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger SourceName="Thumb" Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter Value="{DynamicResource ButtonSelectBrush}" TargetName="Thumb" Property="Background" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger SourceName="Thumb" Property="IsDragging" Value="true">
                                <Setter Value="{DynamicResource DarkBrush}" TargetName="Thumb" Property="Background" />
                            </Trigger>

                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter TargetName="Thumb" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal">
                                <Setter TargetName="GridRoot" Property="LayoutTransform">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <RotateTransform Angle="-90" />
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                                <Setter TargetName="PART_Track" Property="LayoutTransform">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <RotateTransform Angle="-90" />
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                                <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
                                <Setter Property="Height" Value="12" />
                                <Setter TargetName="Thumb" Property="Tag" Value="Horizontal" />
                                <Setter TargetName="PageDown" Property="Command" Value="ScrollBar.PageLeftCommand" />
                                <Setter TargetName="PageUp" Property="Command" Value="ScrollBar.PageRightCommand" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Comment: I've also updated my question to contain a modified version of your code to resemble what I need.