# C# Design Panel Scrollbars

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

I was searching around but didn't really found what I'am looking for . 
My question is : How we can change the look the look of a Panel Scrollbar ?

Thanks

Comment: We need more information than what you have given us. What have you tried, and what framework (winforms, wpf, etc) are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your answer . It's WinForms .
I really don't know from where to begin since I'am new on C sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are going for WinForms. As everyone knows, all you see is pretty much C#. 
And yes, there are ways to create custom scrollbars, but it takes either alot of time (if you dont know what to do) or you'd have to use resources on the internet.

http://www.binarymission.co.uk/products/winforms/scrollbars.html

As you want to style those scrollbars, I recommend using WPF (Windows Presentation Foundation). It it still C#, but this time you'll have more control over the overall layout. This is because WPF supports XML for its layout.

As you can see, you can create a nice Apple looking scrollbar using XML:
[Apple Style Scrollbar WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969292/apple-style-scrollbar-wpf)

I hope this answer helps. :)

Comment: Thanks for Answering .
But I need WinForm Applications . beside the first link .. isn't really what's I need . 
What I need is a Complete Costum ... means some Picture Boxes that Do the Scrolling and ability to change the pictures

Comment: You might want to look at the following URL then. At the comment marked as the answer there are a few helpfull links. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/6ae078d2-c4c8-4a52-95c5-3341466b0471/custom-scrollbar-control?forum=winforms