# WPF, learning to style scrollbar

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am currently in the (for me rather steep) learning curve of WPF and styling. I managed to style most of the controls I use in my application, but now I am hitting a wall: I want to style my scrollbar.

I read a bunch of the documentation on this topic

- [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742173%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969292/apple-style-scrollbar-wpf)
- [Some blog](http://www.thinkbottomup.com.au/site/blog/WPF_Transparent_Scrollbars_in_ScrollView)
- [Another blog...](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37366/Styling-A-ScrollViewer-Scrollbar-In-WPF.aspx)

So it was time to practice. How I started on my previous experiments was just to set a style on a control, ran the application, look at the horrible creations I created, and go from there.

I can't seem to get started with the scrollbar though.

For example, when I add the following style in my Styles.xaml (which is correctly referred to in my Window.Resources, all the other styles for Buttons, TextBlocks, Groupboxes etc, work just fine this way)

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false" />
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}"> 
                <Border 
                    CornerRadius="0"
                    Background="Chartreuse"
                    BorderBrush="Red"
                    BorderThickness="15" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

It does not reflect in any way when I run my application. I tried several styles (copy paste example with TargetType Thumb, TargetType RepeatButton, etc).

Do I need the **complete** style definition of a scrollviewer + scrollbars + repeat button + thumb to get my first visual result?

I would like to start with changing the Thumbs and the Scrollbar itself, just the appearance. I have no idea how to get started, other then copy/pasting 300 lines of xaml from a random blog, which results in me getting lost completely...

Hopefully some WPF style magician can point me in the right direction. As said: preferably a slow step by step route so that I can actually make myself believe that I understand what I am doing :).

Answer (score 4):

So if we go take a look at the [default style templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742173%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you'll see a hard reference to;

`Thumb Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarThumb}"`

So you can either override that x:Key resource it's using in one of multiple ways, or you can style an entire style template that includes the Thumb and incorporates it from there. If you want a reference (albeit is for Silverlight) I can send you the source to one of many themes I did a couple years ago you can dig into if you like since there's no NDA on it, you can view the output [here](http://professionalsweb.net/GleemTheme/GleemTheme-v.05/PrecompiledWeb/TwoToneControlTheme-CWSite/). Which, once you know xaml, you won't care if it's SL, WPF, WP, whatever....

Anyhow, for an immediate fix for you though, you can just override that resource at the instance, something like (pseudo);

```
<ScrollViewer>
   <ScrollViewer.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ScrollBarThumb" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false" />
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}"> 
                <Border 
                    CornerRadius="0"
                    Background="Chartreuse"
                    BorderBrush="Red"
                    BorderThickness="15" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
   </ScrollViewer.Resources>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: Hi Chris, you already taught me a great deal. The part that I can override the "default" key so that it gets picked up by the default control is very helpful! Copy/pasted your fix, nothing visible yet. But, it's probably something stupid on my side. I will look further tomorrow morning! Many thanks so far (will accept the answer when I get it working, or I will come back with more questions :))

Comment: No worries man, we've all been there. Just let me know. Cheers

Comment: are you sure the key is ScrollBarThumb? I just looked at the default template and only found ScrollBarThumbVertical and ScrollBarThumbHorizontal

Comment: @Dominik ctrl+F on the page, you'll see it. I'm just going by that doc, I don't have a WPF proj open at the moment to verify though and we all know that sometimes the MS docs don't exactly match the real deal so who knows lol.

Comment: oh right, I was looking at the default template in Blend

Comment: @Dominik yea, then that might help the dude troubleshoot more moving forward haha...it's a lot easier when you're looking at absolute truth (the code being used) as opposed to the occasionally slightly different docs. Good looking out. ;)

Comment: @Chris yea, for some reason the Microsoft docs are not always up to date

Comment: @ChrisW. Strangely enough it's still not working. I ended up copying your exact example just to see if I made a stupid error somewhere, but even then I can't override the ScrollBarThumb key (or at least, no proof of it when I run my app). I also tried the *Veritcal key Dominik proposed. I can progress by defining a complete Scrollbar style. But I'd still like to understand if I am doing something wrong or if that it's not possible to overwrite keys after all.

Comment: PS: R# is telling me that the key is never used, but I guess that makes sense since I don't directly reference it. Or am I missing an "override"-like keyword somewhere to explain that I am in fact overriding that key?

Comment: Nah, the way it works with inheritance it should grab it from the instance.resources with precedence over the lower one in the style template. You might take a look at the default template and make sure that is indeed the key you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the Scrollbar defines a style for the Thumb and sets it as local value. Therefore you cannot change it using your own style, because local values take precedence over implicit styles.

You can look up the precedence list here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

To edit the style you have two options:

The first one is to overwrite the resources with the key `ScrollBarThumbVertical` and `ScrollBarThumbHorizontal`.

The second is to copy the default template to your own scrollbar and edit these styles directly. The default template of `Scrollbar` is about 250 lines of code, however, you can safely ignore all triggers, which account for about half of the code. It will take a bit time to find you way around it, but I believe it is a good learning experience.