# Advantage of specifying weighted value for single GridUnitType.Star column / row?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I've seen the following on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10976566/1229237), and didn't think much of it. But I've then seen it in the documentation from Microsoft when looking at the [`ScrollBar.ControlTemplate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742173(VS.85).aspx), and thought I must be missing something.

What's the benefit of specifying a weighted value for a `RowDefinition` or `ColumnDefinition` when no other definitions make use of `GridUnitType.Star`?

For example, both those links contain something like:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition MaxHeight="18"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="0.00001*"/>
    <RowDefinition MaxHeight="18"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

My understanding is that this is the same:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition MaxHeight="18"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    <RowDefinition MaxHeight="18"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

So what's the point? Convention, performance, historical? I couldn't see anything in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.gridunittype(v=vs.85).aspx). What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, no other `RowDefinition` is specifying a height, so by default, all `RowDefinition.Height`s are set to *-sized.  So in your first example, this would be equivalent:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*" MaxHeight="18"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="0.00001*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"MaxHeight="18"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Meaning, if Height is < 18 for those two columns, then the second `RowDefinition` will own `0.00001/2.00001` of the available space in the grid.