# C# WPF Scrollbar - Repeat Buttons

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, scrollbar

I would like to change my scrollbar design. I have already changed a few things, but I can't get any further. Ive used this question [Apple Style Scrollbar WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969292/apple-style-scrollbar-wpf) to design my current scrollbar, but i can't manage to design the repeat buttons like in my template.

**Template Scrollbar**

[image: Template Scrollbar]

**Current Scrollbar**

[image: Current Scrollbar]

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledForegroundBrush" Color="#888" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="GlyphBrush" Color="#444" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NormalBrush" Color="#888" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NormalBorderBrush" Color="#888" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="HorizontalNormalBrush" Color="#FF686868" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="HorizontalNormalBorderBrush" Color="#888" />

    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ListBoxBackgroundBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0.001">
        <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStopCollection>
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.0" />
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.6" />
                <GradientStop Color="#DDDDDD" Offset="1.2"/>
            </GradientStopCollection>
        </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="StandardBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
        <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStopCollection>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFF" Offset="0.0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#CCC" Offset="1.0"/>
            </GradientStopCollection>
        </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="PressedBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
        <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStopCollection>
                <GradientStop Color="#BBB" Offset="0.0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#EEE" Offset="0.1"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#EEE" Offset="0.9"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFF" Offset="1.0"/>
            </GradientStopCollection>
        </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <Style x:Key="ScrollBarLineButton" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                    <Border Name="Border" Margin="1" CornerRadius="4" Background="{StaticResource NormalBrush}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource NormalBorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1">
                        <Path HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Fill="{StaticResource GlyphBrush}" Data="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PressedBrush}" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="ScrollBarPageButton" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                    <Border Background="Black" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="ScrollBarThumb" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                    <Border CornerRadius="4" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="0"  Width="8" Margin="0"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="VerticalScrollBar" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition MaxHeight="0"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.00001*"/>
                <RowDefinition MaxHeight="0"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Border Grid.RowSpan="3" CornerRadius="4" Background="LightGray" Width="8" Margin="0, 0, 5 ,0"/>
            <RepeatButton Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarLineButton}" Height="18"  Command="ScrollBar.LineUpCommand" Content="M 0 4 L 8 4 L 4 0 Z" />
            <Track Name="PART_Track" Grid.Row="1" IsDirectionReversed="true">
                <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                    <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}" Command="ScrollBar.PageUpCommand" />
                </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                <Track.Thumb>
                    <Thumb Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarThumb}" Margin="0,0,5,0" Background="{StaticResource HorizontalNormalBrush}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource HorizontalNormalBorderBrush}" />
                </Track.Thumb>
                <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                    <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}" Command="ScrollBar.PageDownCommand" />
                </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
            </Track>
            <RepeatButton Grid.Row="3" Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarLineButton}" Height="18" Command="ScrollBar.LineDownCommand" Content="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z"/>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="HorizontalScrollBar" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="18"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.00001*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="18"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Border Grid.ColumnSpan="3" CornerRadius="2" Background="#F0F0F0"/>
            <RepeatButton Grid.Column="0"  Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarLineButton}" Width="8" Command="ScrollBar.LineLeftCommand" Content="M 4 0 L 4 8 L 0 4 Z" />
            <Track Name="PART_Track" Grid.Column="1" IsDirectionReversed="False">
                <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                    <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}" Command="ScrollBar.PageLeftCommand" />
                </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                <Track.Thumb>
                    <Thumb Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarThumb}" Margin="0,1,0,1" Background="{StaticResource NormalBrush}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource NormalBorderBrush}" />
                </Track.Thumb>
                <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                    <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}" Command="ScrollBar.PageRightCommand" />
                </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
            </Track>
            <RepeatButton Grid.Column="3" Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarLineButton}" Width="8" Command="ScrollBar.LineRightCommand" Content="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 0 8 Z"/>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <Style x:Key="{x:Type ScrollBar}" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="18" />
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource HorizontalScrollBar}" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="18"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto" />
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource VerticalScrollBar}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="FavsScrollViewer" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <ScrollContentPresenter Grid.Column="1"/>
                        <ScrollBar Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"/>
                        <ScrollBar Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Value="{TemplateBinding HorizontalOffset}" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Set the `Visibility` of the `RepeatButton` to `Visible` in the "ScrollBarLineButton" `Style`
- Set the `Height` of the `RowDefinitions` in the "VerticalScrollBar" `Style`
- Also set the `Grid.Row` attached property of the last `RepeatButton` to `2` in in the "VerticalScrollBar" `Style`:

  ```
    <Style x:Key="ScrollBarLineButton" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                    <Border Name="Border" Margin="1" CornerRadius="4" Background="{StaticResource NormalBrush}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource NormalBorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1">
                        <Path HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Fill="{StaticResource GlyphBrush}" Data="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PressedBrush}" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="VerticalScrollBar" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="0.00001*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Border Grid.RowSpan="3" CornerRadius="4" Background="LightGray" Width="8" Margin="0, 0, 5 ,0"/>
            <RepeatButton Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarLineButton}" Height="18"  Command="ScrollBar.LineUpCommand" Content="M 0 4 L 8 4 L 4 0 Z" />
            <Track Name="PART_Track" Grid.Row="1" IsDirectionReversed="true">
                <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                    <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}" Command="ScrollBar.PageUpCommand" />
                </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                <Track.Thumb>
                    <Thumb Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarThumb}" Margin="0,0,5,0" Background="{StaticResource HorizontalNormalBrush}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource HorizontalNormalBorderBrush}" />
                </Track.Thumb>
                <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                    <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}" Command="ScrollBar.PageDownCommand" />
                </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
            </Track>
            <RepeatButton Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarLineButton}" Height="18" Command="ScrollBar.LineDownCommand" Content="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z"/>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

In VerticalScrollBar template you have `<RowDefinition MaxHeight="0"/>`. So row with button has 0 height.